# Discord.py adding timeout for a session

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I add a timeout for a session created by a user and automatically end and remove the session from the list of sessions if x amount of time is reached?

When a user typed `!ses`, the bot will create for a session for that user.

```
import discord


class Session:
    def __init__(self, author, channel):
        self.author = author
        self.channel = channel

    def get_author_id(self):
        return self.author.id


class SessionTest(discord.Client):

    def __init__(self, **options):
        self.sessions = list()
        super().__init__(**options)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot ready.')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if "!ses" in message.content:
            if any(s.get_author_id() == message.author.id for s in self.sessions):
                await message.channel.send("Session already exists.")
            else:
                session = Session(message.author, message.channel)
                msg = format("Session created for %s" % message.author.name)
                await message.channel.send(msg)
                self.sessions.append(session)
        elif "!dos" in message.content:
            ses = next((s for s in self.sessions if s.get_author_id() == message.author.id), None)
            if ses is not None:
                msg = format("Done something for %s" % message.author.name)
                await message.channel.send(msg)
            else:
                await message.channel.send("You don't have a session yet.")


client = SessionTest()
client.run("", bot=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) for the appropriate amount of time, then after that you can remove the session.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if "!ses" in message.content:
        if any(s.get_author_id() == message.author.id for s in self.sessions):
            await message.channel.send("Session already exists.")
        else:
            session = Session(message.author, message.channel)
            msg = format("Session created for %s" % message.author.name)
            await message.channel.send(msg)
            self.sessions.append(session)
            await asyncio.sleep(60)  # One minute
            self.sessions = [s for s in self.sessions if s.get_author_id() != message.author.id]
    elif "!dos" in message.content:
        ses = next((s for s in self.sessions if s.get_author_id() == message.author.id), None)
        if ses is not None:
            msg = format("Done something for %s" % message.author.name)
            await message.channel.send(msg)
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You don't have a session yet.")
```

Comment: How would you end a session automatically if the user isn't sending commands for x amount of time. How would you add a countdown that resets if the user does something?

Comment: In that case you probably need a map of users to (task, Session) pairs, where the task is a coroutine that waits and then removes the session. Everytime the user sends a command you cancel that task and create a new one.  Here's some reading to get started understanding how tasks work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html